# Possible bug with :active selector in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, click, css-selectors

I was compiling different methods to achieve click & show with pure CSS and I am not sure if I found a bug in Firefox. The html code is:

```
<span id="show6" class="show6"></span>
<div id="cont6">Ipsum Lorem</div>
```

The CSS uses the :active selector to make the div visible when the span is clicked:

```
#cont6{
   display: block;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
   opacity: 0; 
   height: 0;
   font-size: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
#show6 {cursor:pointer;}
#show6:before { content: "Show"}
#show6:active.show6:before {content: "Hide"}
#show6:active ~ #cont6{
   opacity: 1;
   font-size: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

(You can see it in action in [Example number 6 or 8 of this dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/319f27a5a1996eb84292). Don't pay much attention to the notes, since they are directed at me but don't really explain the examples).

If I understand :active, the effect should occur only while the span is pressed, and the moment it is released the effect should stop, however in Firefox the div keeps visible after releasing the click on the span.

Can you reproduce it or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I seem to recall seeing this issue before with Firefox, but I'm not sure where exactly, or if it has been reported. I found [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1027179), but it was reported very recently, and I'm not sure how closely related it might be.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks man. That's exactly the issue. I swear I searched for hours in bugzilla and I didn't find anything, so I posted here. Do you know if there is any way to subscribe to that bug without having an account there?